# UTF-16 to UTF-8 conversion (for scripting in Windows)

Tags: windows, utf-8, batch-file, cmd, utf-16

what is the best way to convert a UTF-16 files to UTF-8? I need to use this in a cmd script.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a GNU tool [recode](http://www.gnu.org/software/recode/recode.html) which you can also use on Windows.
E.g.

```
recode utf16..utf8 text.txt
```

Comment: A Windows version of 'recode' can be downloaded as part of the 'GNU utilities for Win32' package from sourceforge: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/unxutils/UnxUtils.zip?modtime=1172730504&big_mirror=0

Comment: Short note - this also works on ubuntu linux with an apt-get install recode. Handy.

Answer (score 15):

An alternative to Ruby would be to write a small .NET program in C# (.NET 1.0 would be fine, although 2.0 would be simpler :) - it's a pretty trivial bit of code. Were you hoping to do it without any other applications at all? If you want a bit of code to do it, add a comment and I'll fill in the answer...

EDIT:
Okay, this is without any kind of error checking, but...

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class FileConverter
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string inputFile = args[0];
    string outputFile = args[1];
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputFile, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
      using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile, false, Encoding.UTF8))
      {
        CopyContents(reader, writer);
      }
    }
  }

  static void CopyContents(TextReader input, TextWriter output)
  {
    char[] buffer = new char[8192];
    int len;
    while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
      output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there is a utility I could just use :) I would be grateful for a bit of code, cheers.

Comment: FYI, here is a little utility based on that code: [https://github.com/paulroho/ConvertToUtf8](https://github.com/paulroho/ConvertToUtf8).

Answer (score 10):

Certainly, the **easiest** way is to load the script into notepad, then save it again with the UTF-8 encoding. It's an option in the Save As dialog box..

Comment: Cheers, I can use it as a workaround, but my script needs to do this conversion, I can't convert every file manually....

Comment: Although it doesn't actually answer the question because it doesn't work in a script, it sure solved my problem!  Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can do this easily with built-in PowerShell cmdlets, which you can invoke from cmd:

```
C:\> powershell -c "Get-Content mytext.txt | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 mytext_utf8.txt"
```

Edit: obviously if you're already in powershell, this would be simplified.  Using aliases would also simplify things:

```
> gc mytext.txt | sc -Encoding utf8 mytext_utf8.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps with [iconv](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/linux/iconv.htm)?

Comment: For everyone who is wondering how it is done:

`iconv -f utf-16le -t utf-8 file.txt > newfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ruby distribution installed, you can call a ruby script taking care of the conversion:

[Ruby script to convert file(s) character encoding](http://www.websideattractions.com/2007/10/24/ruby-script-to-convert-files-character-encoding/)

In the same spirit: [Perl script](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=719216)

In the absence of script support, you would have to code it like this [C++ source](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/utfConvert.aspx) using a WideCharToMultiByte() call...