# convert utf-8 string to Persian unicode

Tags: c#, arabic, persian

I have following string as utf-8. i want convert it to persian unicode:

```
Ø§Ø¨Ø±Ø§Ø² Ø¯Ø§Ø´Øª: Ø§Ù…Ø§Ù… Ø±Ø¶Ø§ Ø¨Ø±Ø®Ø§Ù„Ù� Ø¯ÛŒÚ¯Ø± Ø§Ø¦Ù…Ù‡ Ø¨Ø§ Ø¬Ù†Ú¯ Ù†Ø±Ù…
```

[this site](http://www.forgani.com/top/service/) correctly do convert and result is: ابراز داشت: امام رضا برخالف دیگر ائمه با جنگ نرم

I test many method and ways but can't resolve this problem, for example these two lines did not produce the desired result:

```
string result = Encoding.GetEncoding("all type").GetString(input);
```

and

```
byte[] preambleBytes= Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble();
byte[] inputBytes= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
byte[] resultBytes= preambleBytes.Concat(inputBytes).ToArray();

string result=Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes.ToArray());
string resultAscii=Encoding.Ascii.GetString(inputBytes);
string resultUnicode=Encoding.Unicode.GetString(inputBytes);
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I test `string result = Encoding.GetEncoding("all type").GetString(inpud)` or` Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input) and Encoding.UTF8.GetString` and many other trend.

Comment: It's duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/31960245/298573

Comment: @VahidN , i searched it but i don't see this question. i read your link an understand what is problem. by another search i fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what is problem by reading [What is problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11300580/8010507) and [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057684/8010507) .

when i converted **string to byte[]**, i forced that to convert as **utf-8** format but really i should use **default** format for converting.

```
False converting: 
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
resultString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

But

```
True converting:
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(inputString);
resultString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Tanks for your comments and answers.

Comment: Actually you are using `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")` and `Encoding.Default` can be different in different settings and languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Encoding.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert.aspx).

```
string source = // Your source
byte[] utfb = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
byte[] resb = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-6"), utfb);
string result = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-6").GetString(resb);
```

NOTE: I wasn't sure which standard you wanted so for the example I used ISO-8859-6 (Arabic).

Answer (score 1):

I get bytes by UTF8 and Get String by Default as follow. This worked for me.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
resultString = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
```