# Can't convert HttpResponseMessage with UTF8 encoding

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding, windows-phone-8.1, windows

I'm struggling with the usual conversion issue, but unfortunately I haven't been able to find anything for my specific problem.

My app is receiving a System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage, from a php server, UTF8 encoded, containing some characters like \u00c3\u00a0 (à) and I'm not able to convert them.

```
string message = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
string newmessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
```

This is just one of my try, but nothing happens, the resultring string still has the \u00c3\u00a0 characters.

I have also read some answers like [How to convert a UTF-8 string into Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293994/how-to-convert-a-utf-8-string-into-unicode) but this solution doesn't work for me. This is the solution code:

```
public static string DecodeFromUtf8(this string utf8String)
{
   // copy the string as UTF-8 bytes.
   byte[] utf8Bytes = new byte[utf8String.Length];
   for (int i=0;i<utf8String.Length;++i) {
      //Debug.Assert( 0 <= utf8String[i] && utf8String[i] <= 255, "the char must be in byte's range");
      utf8Bytes[i] = (byte)utf8String[i];
   }

   return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes,0,utf8Bytes.Length);
}

DecodeFromUtf8("d\u00C3\u00A9j\u00C3\u00A0"); // déjà
```

I have noticed that when I try the above solution with a simple string like

```
string str = "Comunit\u00c3\u00a0"
```

the *DecodeFromUtf8* method works perfectly, the problem is when I use my response message.

Any advice would be very appreciated

Comment: why you concatenating original message from variable "message" by not using "newmessage"?

Comment: if you're referring to the debug line I have removed it, it's a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved this problem by myself. I've discovered that the server response was a ISO string of a utf-8 json, so I had to remove the json escape characters and then convert the iso into a utf8

So I had to do the following:

```
private async Task<string> ResponseMessageAsync(HttpResponseMessage result)
{
    string message = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    string parsedString = Regex.Unescape(message);
    byte[] isoBites = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(parsedString);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(isoBites, 0, isoBites.Length);
 }
```

Comment: I had a similar issue. Vendor said the content was UTF-8 and the content-type header said the content type was UTF-8 but I had to use the "ISO-8859-1" encoding to read the response content I got the correct characters returned.

Comment: What actually worked in my case was the reading of the iso bytes and getting the UTF8 string, without actually calling Encoding.Convert

Comment: That exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

for me works change from:

```cs
string message = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
string newmessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
```

to:

```cs
byte[] bytes = await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
string newmessage = utf8.GetString(bytes);
```