# Converting string to Unicode characters

Tags: c#, string, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to Convert a string in to a series of unicode characters.
for expample : if I have a string that contains "Ñ", the unicode I want would be this "U+00D1".
Edit
thank you everyone for your time. What I wanted was the hexadecimal representative  of the unicode character no the character itself encoded in unicode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a UTF-8 string into Unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293994/how-to-convert-a-utf-8-string-into-unicode)

Comment: You mean, you want the hexadecimal representation of each unicode character?

Comment: yes exactly @maf-soft

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are starting from a .NET string instance. That is not "a UTF-8 string". C# and .NET strings are based on `char` values which represent UTF-16 code units.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    string input = "nsa";
    var result = input.Select(t => string.Format("U+{0:X4} ", Convert.ToUInt16(t))).ToList();
```

Or with nicer formatting (C# 6):

```
    string input = "nsa";
    var result = input.Select(t => $"U+{Convert.ToUInt16(t):X4} ").ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using c# 4 and it seems this code needs c# 6 :(

Comment: Keep both versions of the string formatting. The future is with the interpolated strings.

Comment: Why not simply use `(ushort)t` instead of `Convert.ToUInt16(t)`?

Comment: That's also an option

Comment: Note that if the string contains code points over U+FFFF, like `"abc\U00012345def"` in C#, then this method will get the hex values of the surrogate pairs, not of the characters themselves. This may be exactly what you want, of course. If not, use the `StringInfo` class to iterate over the so-called text elements, and use the `char.ConvertToUtf32` on the "text element" to get the numeric value(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not asking about the algorithm itself, then just use [`Encoding.Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye(v=vs.110).aspx).