# How to convert UTF-8 JSON containing Unicode characters to Unicode encoding?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, unicode, utf-8

I am posting JSON requests to an URL using Unity and C#. I am getting back responses in JSON format with texts containing some special characters. Such as: "ó", "ü","é" etc.

For the posting and receiving, I am using the [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class of Unity. I have tried to convert the incoming byte[] the following way:

```
byte[] incomingBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, www.downloadHandler.data);
var str = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(incomingBytes);
Debug.Log(str);
```

It makes no effect on the output. I am still getting the following example text back: `csap\u00e1sra` instead of `csapásra`. Any idea how to get back a field containing special characters from a JSON in Unity/C#?

Comment: Seems like this is what you might be running into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293994/how-to-convert-a-utf-8-string-into-unicode

Comment: Isn't `\u00e1` UTF16 instead of UTF8?

Comment: I've tried barnes53's answer with `DecodeFromUtf8` but no luck still. The weirdest part is if I take the printed text with the `\u` codes and manually add it to a string in my code it works.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use a XML file as workaround.
E.g. my database is in json but the datas who has characters like é, ô, ë are in my XML file.

Comment: You will probably have to provide more details about how exactly to do the workaround you propose. Try for [answer]. If you mainly posted to say "Me too" please delete the post - for which you have to either register first, or flag your own post for a moderator to do the deleting for you.