# Encode UTF8 text to Unicode C#

Tags: c#, decode, encode

How to encode UTF8 text to Unicode?

```
string text_txt = "Ð¿ÑÐ¸Ð²ÐµÑ";    
byte[] bytesUtf8 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text_txt);
text_txt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesUtf8);
```

The problem is output: п�?иве�

I need output: привет

Using that site: https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter enter text in "`UTF-8 text (Example: a ä¸­ Ð¯`)" to "`Ð¿ÑÐ¸Ð²ÐµÑ`" it will show you "привет" on Unicode text

Please give some advice thanks

Comment: do you mean `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytesUtf8);` ?

Comment: No difference by the way. if use it output: 뿐㿑룐닐뗐�

Comment: What is the correct output ?

Comment: I don't think that text is in UTF8. Try using [this site](https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) to find out what encoding that text is in.

Comment: Correct output will be "привет"

Comment: original `text_txt` is *not* UTF8, but native C# encoding. see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11300580/21336

Comment: @J.Col I can't reproduce the behaviour you described in the edit...

Comment: `Encoding.Default` can *vary* from workstation to workstation (it may be `Win-1251`, `Win-1252`, `Win-1255` etc); in case of .Net **Core** it's `UTF-8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   byte[] utf8Bytes = new byte[text_txt.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < text_txt.Length; ++i)
                {
                    //Debug.Assert( 0 <= utf8String[i] && utf8String[i] <= 255, "the char must be in byte's range");
                    utf8Bytes[i] = (byte)text_txt[i];
                }
                text_txt= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes, 0, text_txt.Length);
```

from answer: [How to convert a UTF-8 string into Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293994/how-to-convert-a-utf-8-string-into-unicode)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably mean this:

```
// Forward: given in UTF-8 represented in WIN-1252

  byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("привет");
  string text = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(data);

// Reverse: given in WIN-1252 represented in UTF-8

  byte[] reversedData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes("Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚");
  string reversedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reversedData);

  Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(" ", data)} <=> {text}");
  Console.WriteLine(reversedText);
```

**Outcome:**

```
208 191 209 128 208 184 208 178 208 181 209 130 <=> Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚
привет
```

Please, note that you've omitted `€` and `,` characters:

```
 Ð¿Ñ Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ  - actual string
 Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚ - should be
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to be explicit about the type of encoding you're using to convert to bytes, (Syste.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes). eg:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        string text_txt = "Ð¿ÑÐ¸Ð²ÐµÑ";

        byte[] bytesUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text_txt);
        text_txt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesUtf8);

        Console.WriteLine(text_txt);
    }
}
```

This way UTF8 is used to both **encode** and decode the string *the same way*, and when you ensure the same string comes back from the GetString method.

Comment: Did you try it on your console? Nothing converted..

Comment: His original post converted "Ð¿ÑÐ¸Ð²ÐµÑ" to п�?иве�. I assumed this was his issue, but I'm otherwise unclear on why the poster expects the input should produce "привет" rather then the input once reversed.