# How do I get the Unicode values of a multipoint character in C#?

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

= (\ud835\udc00) in UTF16

How do I do this conversion in C#?

The following code doesn't allow me to enter the character above. It throws the error **"Too many characters in character literal"** I guess it's because the char is multi point.

```
string hex = ((int)'').ToString("X4");
string hex = ((int)'A').ToString("X4");// This works
```

A help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check this similar questions answered here. [I think this may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293994/how-to-convert-a-utf-8-string-into-unicode/14775141#14775141)

Comment: Check this similar questions answered here. [I think this may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293994/how-to-convert-a-utf-8-string-into-unicode/14775141#14775141)

Comment: Here are some dotNet/PowerShell hints (I'm too lazy converting them to C#). `[char[]]''|ForEach-Object{([int]$_).ToString("X4")}` returns `D835`,`DC00`  surrogate pair; `([char]::ConvertToUtf32('',0)).ToString("X")` returns codepoint `1D400`  (more than 4 hexa digits). The `[char]` type has a static string method `ConvertFromUtf32(int utf32)` etc…