# how to deocde some coded text in c#

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, .net-4.5, decoding

I have a html text that provides from a server. but persian letters does not appears correctly.
for example like this :

```
Ø¬Ø´Ù† Ù†ÙˆØ±ÙˆØ²/Ø¬Ø´Ù† Ø³Ø§Ù„ Ù†Ùˆ
```

I have used this extension method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11300580 to decode this text

```
public static string DecodeFromUtf8(this string utf8String)
{
    // copy the string as UTF-8 bytes.
    byte[] utf8Bytes = new byte[utf8String.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < utf8String.Length; ++i)
    {
         utf8Bytes[i] = (byte)utf8String[i];
    }

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length);
}
```

but It will return this :

```
جش�  � ��ر��ز/جش�  سا�\u001e � ��
```

I am using .net framework 4.5 . if anyone help me how to crack this I would be appreciated.

Comment: What viewer are you using?  It looks like you are viewing in a console window and the console is not set to the correct encoding.  So the code is correct, just need to view with correct settings.

Comment: @jdweng I did not print out any thing. I just want save it to database. I notice that when I was debug my code

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes it was. thanks

Comment: The string is probably correct and just while debugging VS was showing data in default encoding.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696627/how-to-set-standard-encoding-in-visual-studio

Comment: The number of bytes in a utf8 encoded string is not equal to the number of characters. For starters a char is 2 bytes.