# Microsoft graph calendar subject not correct for Chinese

Tags: c#, encoding, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft's graph API to get calendar events.

For Chinese, the Subject field text for the Event is nonsense.

For example, "世界您好" becomes "ä¸–ç•Œæ‚¨å¥½"

Microsoft's Graph API is returning correct data. The only problem is I don't know the encoding for the Subject field of each Event.

Comment: `var utf8 = Encoding.Default;` self-trolling turned to all the way to 11... naming some random encoding `utf8` does not really make code any more readable, even `a` or `l` would be less confusing.  Could you please review your code and make sure to post [MCVE] into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on an answer from [Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293994/how-to-convert-a-utf-8-string-into-unicode/11301195#11301195), it seems Microsoft Graph is encoding Calendar Events using "[code page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which is US Windows default".

Using his answer, this gave me the correct Subject field for the events.

```
public static string DecodeFromUtf8(this string utf8String)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(utf8String);
    byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, bytes);
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(unicodeBytes);
}
```