# Need help converting escaped Unicode back to original string

Tags: c#, utf-8

I have this string that was UTF8 encoded from PHP.

Encoded value : `tr\u008fs`

How do I get the original value back using C#?

The original value should be `très`.

Comment: There is some code to do this conversion [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/convert-a-unicode-string-to-an-escaped-ascii-string)

Comment: Is that encoded value definitely correct? I would expect è to be \u00e8 rather than \u008f
And Damjan's solution works with the former but not the latter.

Comment: Jon is right. The initial character should be \u00e8 instead of \u008f 
(as per: https://unicode-table.com/en/#00E8)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144568/storing-a-string-as-utf8-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Jon, You are right. I didn't see this. This is probably the issue. Thanks for pointing this out. I need to investigate.

Comment: The code you've shown is an escaped Unicode code point, *not* UTF-8.  If anything you are converting *back* to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
string s = "tr\u008fs";            
string value = encoding.GetString(encoding.GetBytes(s));
```