# git show HEAD~1:.gitignore command results in weird characters in Windows 64bit

Tags: windows, git

I have these lines written in my .gitignore file:

```
logs/
main.log
*.log
bin/
*.bin
```

When i execute the command: git show HEAD~1:.gitignore, i get this weird result:
[git command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjQjn.png)

When i'm supposed to get this: [extected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnawa.png)

I run this command from poweshell, cmd, git bash, windows terminal and Cygwin64 and from the integrated terminal in VS Code and i get the same result from everywhere. .gitignore's encoding is UTF-16 LE. I even changed the encoding to ANSI and UTF-8 but still got the same result. Stuck with this one for days, any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `<FF><FE>` is a *byte order mark* or *BOM* that marks the file as UTF-16-LE.  The remainder of the file consists of UTF-16-LE characters.  That is, this isn't a plain text file, it's a UTF-16 file.  Git does not know how to read that (and the result is that its contents don't actually matter).

> I even changed the encoding to ANSI and UTF-8 but still got the same result.

The actual bytes of the file matter: a UTF-8 file would, ideally, *not* begin with a BOM (UTF-8 files don't have byte order in the first place so these are just junk).  The entire text of the file would then just be the UTF-8 data.  This requires rewriting the file, i.e., you will need to make a new commit: the existing commit has a useless file in it.

To actually rewrite the file, you will need a tool that does it.  You do not say *how* you changed the encoding.  See [UTF-16 to UTF-8 conversion (for scripting in Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/265370/1256452) for various options.  It's possible you've already done this correctly, and made a new commit, because `HEAD~1` is not the *current* commit, but rather some existing, *previous* commit.  No existing commit can ever be changed, though the special name `HEAD` always refers to the *current* commit, so as you make new commits, the commit that `HEAD` means—and therefore the one that `HEAD~1` means—changes over time.

Comment: i changed the encoding by opening and saving it as UTF-8 and ANSI, i didn't use a tool, but i'll try what you 're suggesting